# What is the unit for spark.network.timeout property without postfix? Seconds or milliseconds?

Tags: apache-spark

If the spark.network.timeout defined without any postfix (s or ms) like this:

```
spark.network.timeout 600
```

is that second or millisecond?

The default value on the https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html
is also defined with postfix "120s"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the [lines](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/HeartbeatReceiver.scala#L75-L80) in `HeartbeatReceiver` it *seems* that `spark.network.timeout` is in seconds.

```
// "spark.network.timeout" uses "seconds", while `spark.storage.blockManagerSlaveTimeoutMs` uses
// "milliseconds"
private val slaveTimeoutMs =
  sc.conf.getTimeAsMs("spark.storage.blockManagerSlaveTimeoutMs", "120s")
private val executorTimeoutMs =
  sc.conf.getTimeAsSeconds("spark.network.timeout", s"${slaveTimeoutMs}ms") * 1000
```

The official documentation of Spark in [Spark Properties](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#spark-properties) says:

> Properties that specify some time duration should be configured with a unit of time.
>
> Properties that specify a byte size should be configured with a unit of size.

Hard to find, but hopefully it becomes easier with your question and my answer.

Comment: They should mention it in the documentation, because the default '120s' implies that the second 's' postfix should be used.